# Clear date picker component after pressing clear button in antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, antd

We are using antd for datepicker and moments as util. I'm stuck for a week in this ISSUE.The thing is, in the filter sidepanel,on pressing clear,all the fields should clear or set to their default values(in case of dropdown).But the date picket is  not resetting.

[image]

The above picture is the Activity component and left side to its his the filter.A basic filter with API change from backend on every action event.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if(clearFilter){
      form.resetFields()
      setActivitySearchText('')
      setFromDate('')
      setToDate('')
      setStatusSearchText('')
      onStatusChange('')
      setClearFilter(false)
    }
  },[clearFilter])

const onChangeFromDate = dateString => {
    setFromDate(new Date(dateString).toISOString())
  }

  const onPageToDate = dateString => {
    setToDate(new Date(dateString).toISOString())
  }

<StyledDatePicker
          allowClear={false}
          format={dateFormat}
          disabledDate={disabledFromDate}
          placeholder={'From'}
          onChange={(fromdate, dateString) =>
            onChangeFromDate(fromdate, dateString)
          }
          showTime={{
            use12Hours: true,
            defaultValue: moment('00:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss'),
          }}
        />
        <StyledDatePicker
          format={dateFormat}
          disabledDate={disabledToDate}
          placeholder={'To'}
          onChange={(todate, dateString) => onPageToDate(todate, dateString)}
          showTime={{ use12Hours: true }}
        />
```

The above code is the index file for all the components,we'll be passing `clearfilter` prop,if its true ,the filter components are set to empty.The `StyledDatePicker` is just wrapped in styled components of some custom width.that's it.

You can clearly see,`onChangeFromDate()` and `onPageToDate()` are the event functions happening on Change,`onChange`. As I said above,I'm setting the `setFromDate('')` and `setTodate('')` when `clearFilter` is `true`.

To give some context,this another main file,from which the props are passed to the others.In there,we are defining `setFromDate('')` and `setTodate('')` as,

```
const [fromDate, setFromDate] = useState('')
  const [toDate, setToDate] = useState('')
```

I think I've given enough details. If need anything, request, I'm ready to give. This is a live project, I'm stuck for a week.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Aashiq, I created a sandbox with a working example close to your code. Give a look and try to find the differences with your code. https://codesandbox.io/s/advanced-search-antd4112-forked-k1y6y

Comment: Yeah, thanks man, I was missing the `value` prop, and a little caveat is, we are using and 3.x, as a junior dev, I can't change the package/upgrade , you know right, it's a big project.btw sorry for the late response ;-)